# vscode dynamic es6 module import error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

vscode does not seems to support es6 import when used as a function to load dynamic chucks.

import is actually supported by webpack 2 + babel.

There are no issue with normal es6 imports or when using async functions.

Eslint was also reporting an error until I integrated babel-eslint.

I am using vscode version 1.9.1

[image]

I tried using a jsconfig.json but it did not change anything

```
{
    // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=759670
    // for the documentation about the jsconfig.json format
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "jspm_packages",
        "tmp",
        "temp"
    ]
}
```

Comment: `import` expressions are not valid ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic imports are now supported by TypeScript ([v2.4.x](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/)) and VSCode since June 2017 release ([v1.14.x](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_languages)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think dynamic imports are part of ES6, and they aren't supported by TypeScript yet (which drives the JS language service) so I think you'll have to use `require`.

Comment: I think it's OK to use the `import()` syntax if you are transpiling it via [babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack) or if you're using webpack 2.x. The problem is getting VSCode to stop recognizing it as an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `"javascript.validate.enable": false` in the preferences and use another syntax validation (for example https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode).